# Differences between `input` and `raw_input`

Tags: python

In a tutorial, I read that that there is a difference between `input` and `raw_input`. I discovered that they changed the behavior of these functions in the Python 3.0. What is the new behavior?

And why in the python console interpreter this

```
x = input()
```

Sends an error but if I put it in a file.py and run it, it does not?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In python 2.x, `raw_input()` returns a string and `input()` evaluates the input in the execution context in which it is called

```
>>> x = input()
"hello"
>>> y = input()
x + " world"
>>> y
'hello world'
```

In python 3.x, `input` has been scrapped and the function previously known as `raw_input` is now `input`. So you have to manually call `compile` and than `eval` if you want the old functionality.

```
python2.x                    python3.x

raw_input()   --------------> input()               
input()  -------------------> eval(input())
```

In 3.x, the above session goes like this

```
>>> x = eval(input())
'hello'
>>> y = eval(input())
x + ' world'
>>> y
'hello world'
>>>
```

So you were probably getting an error at the interpretor because you weren't putting quotes around your input. This is necessary because it's evaluated. Where you getting a name error?

Comment: Whats going on here i tried your lines on the console (3.x) and it interpreted 
x = input()
"hello" <-- i type this on the console when asked)
x + " world"
y
'x + "world"
Why? x is not translated into a string

Comment: the error i was getting 
>>> x = input()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
EOFError: EOF when reading a line

Comment: @Guillermo, The interpreter section I showed is for 2.x. I messed up on 3.x (i haven't played with it much at all) so I deleted that part of my answer.

Comment: Mmm maybe i should start learning python 2.X i just wanted to have the latest with most future learning. but i don't want to get stuck like this as is a such a waste of time, i guess i could find another tutorial.

Comment: @Guillermo, that's my final answer. Also, there's nothing that's a waste of time in the processes of learning. It turns out that I did have my understanding of 3.x right, I just tried to do something different in it. Why do you think you're wasting your time?

Comment: I mean i don't want to learn something that is on its way of being depreceated like python 2.x. i think i'm just trying to learn the most efficient way. Thanks for your time, i tried the code you used and it worked as it should, the problem with the interpreter was that i'm using the notepad++ python plugin console and it does weird stuff i won't mess with it anymore i'll stick with the default one.

Answer (score 3):

**input() vs raw_input()**

raw_input collects the characters the user types and presents them as a string.
 input() doesn't just evaluate numbers but rather treats any input as Python code and tries to execute it. Knowledgeable but malicious user could type in a Python command that can even deleted a file. Stick to raw_input() and convert the string into the data type you need using Python's built in conversion functions.

Also input(), is not safe from user errors! It expects a valid Python expression as input; if the input is not syntactically valid, a SyntaxError will be raised.

Answer (score 3):

Its simple:

1. `raw_input()` returns string values
2. while `input()` return integer values

For Example:

1.

```
x = raw_input("Enter some value = ")
print x
```

Output:

```
Enter some value = 123
'123'
```

2.

```
y = input("Enter some value = ") 
print y
```

Output:

```
Enter some value = 123
123
```

Hence if we perform `x + x =` It will output as 123123

while if we perform `y + y =` It will output as 246

Comment: Maybe on python 2.x, but not on python 3.x. input() in python 3.x always return a string. Moreover, raw_input() has been deleted from python 3