# Python selection sort

Tags: python, sorting, select, integer

Question: The code is supposed to take a file (that contains one integer value per line), print the (unsorted) integer 
values, sort them, and then print the sorted values.

Is there anything that doesn't look right? I know I could test it and I did test the selectionSort, which worked fine. But I don't really know how I could test whether it successfully takes the file and does what its supposed to do.

Thank you

```
filename=input('Enter file path:')
file = open(filename, 'r')
alist = [int(line) for line in file.readlines()]
print(alist)

def selectionSort(alist):
    for index in range(0, len(alist)):
        ismall = index
        for i in range(index,len(alist)):
            if alist[ismall] > alist[i]:
                ismall = i
        alist[index], alist[ismall] = alist[ismall], alist[index]
    return alist
```

Comment: To test it, why don't you just create a file with numbers and run your script on it?

Answer (score 1):

Your selection sort seems to be correct but the part before it has issues:

(I am assuming this is Python 2.X, if it isn't ignore my answer)

- [You need to use `raw_input` not `input`.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800846/differences-between-input-and-raw-input)
- [`file.readlines()` doesn't get rid of the `\n` at the end of every line. You need to strip it away.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15233340/getting-rid-of-n-when-using-readlines)

The corrected code:

```
filename=raw_input('Enter file path:')
file = open(filename, 'r')
alist = [int(line.strip()) for line in file.readlines()]
print(alist)
```

Answer (score 0):

change your  3rd line to

```
alist = [int(line.strip()) for line in file.readlines()]
```

From

```
alist = [int(line) for line in file.readlines()]
```