# Selection sort program python

Tags: python, sorting

So this is supposed to be a sorting program, but for some reason, it is not sorting the file I'm giving, but just giving me straight numbers as it is. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

```
filename=input('Enter file path:')
file = open(filename, 'r')
alist = [(line) for line in file.readlines()]
print(alist)

def selectionSort(alist):
    for index in range(0, len(alist)):
        ismall = index
        for i in range(index,len(alist)):
            if alist[ismall] > alist[i]:
                ismall = i
        alist[index], alist[ismall] = alist[ismall], alist[index]
    return alist
```

Comment: Why do you wrap a list comprehension around `readlines`, which already gives you a list?

Comment: What's with all these SelectionSort questions today? This is very similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22121364/python-selection-sort/22121507#22121507

Comment: This function works fine for me in Python 3.3. It successfully sorts a text file with 9700 (partial) genetic codes.

Comment: lol it was the homework that's why @Nitish

Answer (score 1):

You didn't call the function!

```
def selectionSort(alist):
    for index in range(0, len(alist)):
        ismall = index
        for i in range(index,len(alist)):
            if alist[ismall] > alist[i]:
                ismall = i
        alist[index], alist[ismall] = alist[ismall], alist[index]

filename=input('Enter file path:')
file = open(filename, 'r')
alist = file.readlines()

# Call the function!
selectionSort(alist)
print(alist)
```

You've told Python what `selectionSort` means, but you haven't told it to sort anything. You need to call `selectionSort(alist)` to actually perform the sort.

Also, the order you want the list to be sorted in is most likely not the order you're telling Python to sort it in. `alist` is a list of strings, so you're telling Python to use lexicographic comparison to order the list. If it's supposed to be treated as, say, integers, you need to convert the data to integers:

```
alist = [int(line) for line in file]
```

(Also, since `selectionSort` modifies the list it operates on, it's best not to return the list. If you return it, it gives the impression that it creates a new, sorted list.)

Comment: it is giving me the same result, it doesn't sort from least to greatest

Comment: @user3369517: You're probably telling Python to compare things the wrong way. Answer expanded.

Comment: alist = [int(line) for line in file] i actually did try that before, but it didn't work because i added int there, i did again now, it is actually giving errors now, "invalid literal for int() with base 10:  "

Comment: What's the actual data? Can you show the data you're trying to sort?

Comment: [45, 7, 5, 25, 24, 1] just that for now

Comment: @user3369517: Does the file actually contain brackets and commas? If so, you need to parse that with something like `ast.literal_eval` first.

Comment: nope, it doesn't contain brackets, i just put it there

Comment: @user3369517: You're going to want to inspect your data file, then. Make sure you're looking at the right file. Make sure it doesn't have any weird non-numeric characters, including Unicode stuff. Make sure it doesn't have anything besides your data.

Answer (score 0):

You have simply defined a method. You need to call it from somewhere. I added to your code and tested it. It works. Here you go: The last two lines actually make a call to the code you created: (be careful about indentation)

```
alist = [42,54,2,45,6,125,32]
print(alist)

def selectionSort(alist):
    for index in range(0, len(alist)):
        ismall = index
        for i in range(index,len(alist)):
            if alist[ismall] > alist[i]:
                ismall = i
        alist[index], alist[ismall] = alist[ismall], alist[index]
    return alist

newList = selectionSort(alist)
print newList
```