# Python If Statement definition error

Tags: python, if-statement, undefined

I'm trying to test out if statements with the use of letters instead of numbers. I'm not sure what the error in my code is, can someone please help out

```
ppp=input('Enter a, or b. or exit to exit')

while ppp!='exit':

    if ppp=='a' or ppp=='A':
        print('You Picked A')
        ppp=input('a,b, or c?: ')

    elif ppp=='b' or ppp=='B':
        print('You Picked B')
        ppp==input('a,b, or c?: ')

    else:
        print ('please choose a, or b')
```

When running it, it prints "Enter a, or b. or exit to exit" but when entering anything whether a, A, b, B, exit, or any random word or letter or number I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "temp.py", line 1, in <module>
   ppp=input('Enter a, or b. or exit to exit')
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'a' is not defined
```

Please someone tell me what's wrong with my code.

Comment: If you're using python 2, use `raw_input` instead of `input`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `input` function in python2, it should be `raw_input()` instead.

```
ppp=raw_input('Enter a, or b. or exit to exit')
```

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3800862/4099593) answer for more information