# Python Inline statement is slower than normal forloop

Tags: python, python-2.7, input, io, raw-input

I was trying a coding contest just now.

I was given N lines of inputs are integer, so take those inputs , I used the following code.

```
arr = [int(input()) for i in xrange(N)]

# where N is a given number of Inputs
```

Due to this piece of code, I was getting TLE ( TIME LIMIT EXCEEDED ) Error.

But when I change the input code to the following, my code gets accepted without TLE.

```
arr = []
for i in xrange(N):
    arr.append(int(raw_input()))

#where N is the given number of inputs
```

Can some please explain, why is there are difference in execution time, though , to my understanding, both the forms of code necessarily do the same task and in the same manner.

Comment: [raw_input vs input](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800846/differences-between-input-and-raw-input)

Answer (score 5):

The two code snippets are different.  One uses `raw_input()`, the other one uses `input()`.  `raw_input()` is expected to be faster than `input()` since it doesn't parse and evaluate the input string as a Python expression.

Comment: my bad ! should have noticed that ! Thanks !