# Python trying to parse input

Tags: python, python-2.x

I'm new to python and have problems with input.
When I'm using command `userName = input('What is your name? ')`
it says something like this:

```
>>> userName = input('What is your name? ')
What is your name? Name
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'Name' is not defined
```

What I must do with it?

Comment: Which version of Python are you using? If you're using Python 2, you should call `raw_input` instead of `input`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Differences between \`input\` and \`raw\_input\`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800846/differences-between-input-and-raw-input)

Comment: You seem to be using Python 2. Your code would be valid Python 3, but you indeed have to change `input` to `raw_input` in your case, as per @Andy comment

Answer (score 2):

change it to :

```
userName = raw_input('What is your name?')
```

In Python 2.x:

`raw_input()` returns string values and
`input()` attempts to evaluate the input as command

But in python 3.x, input has been scrapped and the function previously known as raw_input is now input.

Comment: `input` doesn't return integer values, it attempts to evaluate the input as Python code.

Comment: The docs say `Equivalent to eval(raw_input(prompt))`, not `Equivalent to int(raw_input(prompt))`.

Comment: @VincentSavard That's right! Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 1):

The function `input()` evaluates input as a command--that is why numbers work, but not generic strings that cannot be executed. To achieve attaching a string to a variable, use the more universal `raw_input()`, which reads everything as a string.

Your new code will now look like

```
userName = raw_input('What is your name? ')
```

Best of luck, and happy coding!