# Python program giving unexpected results, why?

Tags: python

My python program is giving unexpected results within the regular expressions functions, when I enter a number plate for recognition, it tells me it's invalid, although it is valid and I don't know why?

I would be grateful if you could tell me what's wrong and give a possible solution, as this is a very important homework assignment.

```
#Start
#04/02/2016
bad=[]#initialise bad list
data="Y"#initialise value to prevent infinite loop
standardNumberPlateObj=""
NumPlate=""
import re#import re functions
import pickle#import pickle function

print ("Welcome to the number plate recognition program.\n\n")
choice=input("Press 1 to input number plates and save\nPress 2 to read binary number plate file: ")
if choice == "1":
        while data=="Y":# while loop
            NumPlate = input("Input Registration number in format (XX01 XXX) *With a space at the end!*:\n\n") #user input for numberplate
            standardNumberPlateObj=re.match(r'\w\w\d\d\s\w\w\w\s', NumPlate, re.M|re.I)#validate that numberplate is valid

            if standardNumberPlateObj:
                print("Verification Success")
                data=input(str("Would you like to continue? (Y/N):"))

            else:
                print("Verification Failed")
                bad.append(NumPlate)#add numberplate to bad list
                data=input(str("Would you like to continue? (Y/N):"))#ask user to continue


        while data=="N":#saving number plates to file if user enters N
             f = open("reg.dat", "wb")
             pickle.dump(bad, f)
             f.close()
             print ("\nRestart the program to read binary file!")#ending message
             break

elif choice == "2":
             print ("\nBad number plates:\n\n")
             f=open("reg.dat", "rb")
             Registrations = pickle.load(f)
             print(Registrations)
             f.close()

else:
             print ("Please enter a valid choice!")

print ("\n END of program!")
```

Comment: What is your input, exactly, when it is invalid?

Comment: BTW, why are you converting strings to strings? Eg, `str("Would you like to continue? (Y/N):")`

Comment: And beware that `input` interprets the input!

Comment: more detail please mastov?

Comment: I was referring to this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3800862/4271479 But if you are using Python 3 then it's fine.

Answer (score 0):

It's not really possible to tell without an example input and the expected and the actual result.

But judging from the expression `\w\w\d\d\s\w\w\w\s` and your example in the prompt (`XX01 XXX`), I'd say that your regular expression is expecting a space in the end, while your input doesn't provide one.

Comment: I have to wait for the time limit, otherwise i would of. :(