# New to programming and trying to finish this task for school, I can't seem to add numbers in a list together

Tags: python

I have a bit of code thats for a task we have to complete for school. I'm trying to add some numbers in a list so I can average that number. Whenever I try to do this it just tells me its an unsupported operand type for int and str. I think what I have to do is convert the inputs into floats rather than strings but I'm not sure how to. Code below:

```
final = False
while final == False: 
    judgeScoreForLoop = 0
    judgeScoreLoop = []

    while True:
        try:
            eventName = str(input("What is the event's name? "))
            numberJudges = int(input("How many judges are there? "))
            competitorName = str(input("What is the competitor's name? "))
            for judgeScoreForLoop in range (0, numberJudges):
                judgeScore = input("Enter the judge score here: ")
                judgeScoreLoop.append(judgeScore)
                judgeScoreForLoop + 1
            break
        except ValueError:
            print("One of the inputs was invalid, please try again.")

    finalJudges = numberJudges - 2

    judgeScoreCombined = sum(judgeScoreLoop)
    judgeFinalScore = judgeScoreCombined / finalJudges

    if competitorName == "Finish".lower():
        final = True

    print(judgeFinalScore)
```

Comment: inputs are strings by default; what you need to do is convert the `judgeScore` values to integers (or floats) before appending them to the list

Comment: Also, side-note, `judgeScoreForLoop + 1` is pointless; your loop is already incrementing it, and even if it weren't, you never assigned the result of the addition, so it just gets thrown away.

Comment: Note that the `input()` function is different between Python 2 and Python 3.  It would be useful to add which one you're using.  Ex. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800846/differences-between-input-and-raw-input

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can convert the input straight into a float

```
  judgeScore = float(input("Enter the judge score here: "))
```

But it might be best to check if the user has supplied a number first by
prehaps using isdigit() I don't want to give too much away but that should help