# Python input never equals an integer

Tags: python

I want to insert a number and if I put any number other than 4 it will tell me it's wrong, but if it's false it will tell me "gg you win, noob.". However when I insert 4, it tells me it's incorrect.

```
x = input("Insert a numer: ")

while x != 4:
   print("incorrect")
    x =input("Insert another number: ")

if x == 4:
    print("gg you win, noob")
```

Comment: Python 2 or Python 3 ?

Comment: Fair assumption he's talking about 3, since this works in 2.

Comment: @brianpck It is a fair assumption, but I would not say it exactly _"works"_ in 2. The code is wrong either way, but with a different problem.

Comment: @brianpck yes. It's python 3

Answer (score 3):

In Python 3+, `input` returns a string, and `4` does not equal `'4'`. You will have to amend to:

```
while x != '4':
```

or alternatively use `int`, being careful to check for a `ValueError` if the input is not an int.

Comment: Python 2 vs 3: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800846/differences-between-input-and-raw-input

Answer (score 2):

The result from `input()` will be a string, which you'll need to convert to an integer before comparing it:

```
x = int(input("Insert another number: ")
```

This will raise a `ValueError` if your input is not a number.

Answer (score 0):

Here, `if x == 4` is not necessary. Because until `x` is equal to `4` the `while` loop won't be passed. You can try like this:

```
x = int(input("Insert a numer: "))
while x != 4:
    print("incorrect")
    x = int(input("Insert another number: "))

print("gg you win, noob")
```

Answer (score 0):

Python 2 and 3 differ in the function `input()`.

- In Python 2, `input()` is equivalent to `eval(raw_input())`.
- In Python 3, there is no `raw_input()`, but `input()` works like Python 2's`raw_input()`.

In your case:

- In Python 2, `input()` gives you `4` with type `int`, so your program works.
- In Python 3, `input()` gives you `'4'` with type `str`, so your program is buggy.

In Python 3, one way to fix this is to use `eval(input())`. But using `eval` on an untrusted string is very dangerous (yes your program works dangerously in Python 2). So you should validate the input first.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    z = 0
while z != "gg you win, noob":
    try:
       x = int(input("Insert a numer: "))
       while x != 4:
           print("incorrect")
           x =int(input("Insert another number: "))

       if x == 4:
            z = "gg you win, noob"
            print(z)

    except:
        print('Only input numbers')
```

This will convert all your input values into integers. If you do not input an integer, the `except` statement will prompt you to only input numbers, and the `while True` loop will repeat your script from the beginning instead of raising an error.