# Do you know what is wrong with this simple script

Tags: python, input

All Im trying to do is make n a random number, if the user gets it correct it outputs "You got it!" but no matter what is always displays as if I got it wrong, even when I answered n

```
import random

n = random.randint(1,2)
guess = input("1 or 2?")
if guess == n:
  print("You won!")
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python input never equals an integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39775273/python-input-never-equals-an-integer)

Answer (score 2):

In python, `"10" == 10` is `False`. You must compare the same type, like `10 == 10` or `"10" == "10"`.

`input()` returns a `str`, when `random.randint()` returns an `int`, so `guess == n` will always be `False`.

This is an easy way to solve your issue :

```
guess = int(input("1 or 2?"))
```

or

```
n = str(random.randint(1, 2))
```

or

```
n = random.choice("12")
```