# What are the variables in this code?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, variables

I've written the code below and need to fill out a variable table like this:

> - Variable name:
> - Type:
> - Validation:
> - Description:

for all variables. However, as I am really really new to python I don't know what the variables are, let alone their details.

I found this example:

> - Variable name: `userName`
> - Type: `String`
> - Validation: `Must only contain characters a-z/A-Z.`
> - Description: `Will be used to store the user’s name.`

But I don't know how to do it for the variables in my code. Please help if you can.

```
print("Please enter a sentence")
sentence=input ()
lowersen=(sentence.lower () )
print(lowersen)
splitlowersen=(lowesen.strip () )
splitlowersen = "".join(c for c in splitlowersen if c not in ('!','.',':','?',';'))
print("Enter word")
word=input()
lword=(word.lower () )
if lword in splitlowersen:
    print(lword, "is in sentence")
    for i, j in enumerate (splitlowersen) :
        if j==lword:
            print(""+lword+"","is in position", i+1)

if lword not in splitlowersen:
    print (lword, "is not in sentence")

print ("End")
```

Comment: Maybe start [here](https://www.learnpython.org/en/Variables_and_Types). I don't understand what you mean by "Validation", as assigning a variable in python has no restriction on what that variable might hold - after assigning that variable one could test it, but there are no such tests in your example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i don't know Phython well but i think it is

Variable name: lword

Type: String

Validation: contains letters, numbers and special characters .

Description: Will be used to check if this word is in the sentence you wrote earlier

That would be for the variable lword

Comment: sentence, lowersen, splitlowersen, word, i and j are the other variables as i can see so far

Answer (score 0):

By the way, you can write this:

```
print(“Please enter a sentence”)
sentence=input ()
```

as this:

```
sentence=input(“Please enter a sentence”)
```

Regarding your question, I will give you an example and continue by your own.
Example:
Variable name: sentence

Type: String

Validation: It may contain letters, numbers, special characters and white spaces.

Description: It is a complete sentence.

Answer (score 0):

I changed your code a bit, hope this helps:

```
sentence = raw_input("Please enter a sentence: ")
# Variable name: `sentence`
# Type: string
# Validation: ?
# Description: the original inputted sentence.
lowersen = sentence.lower()
# Variable name: `lowersen`
# Type: string
# Validation: ?
# Description: the inputted sentence in lowercase only.
print(lowersen)
splitlowersen = lowersen.strip()
# Variable name: `splitlowersen`
# Type: string
# Validation: ?
# Description: lowersen with leading and trailing whitespace removed...
forb_symbs = ('!', '.', ':', '?', ';') # not originally in the example!
splitlowersen = "".join(c for c in splitlowersen if c not in forb_symbs)
# Description (cont.): ... and without the symbols in the list `forb_symbs`
splitlowersen = splitlowersen.split(' ') # not originally in the example!
# Variable name: `splitlowersen`
# Type: list
# Validation: ?
# Description: la list of words in the sentence.

word = raw_input("Enter one word: ")
# Variable name: `word`
# Type: string
# Validation: ?
# Description: the original inputted word.
lword = word.lower()
# Variable name: `lword`
# Type: string
# Validation: ?
# Description: the original inputted word in lowercase only.

if lword in splitlowersen:
    print('"' + lword + '" is in sentence!')
    for i, j in enumerate(splitlowersen):
        # Variable name: `i`
        # Type: int
        # Validation: ?
        # Description: index of the list currently being probbed 
        # Variable name: `j`
        # Type: string
        # Validation: ?
        # Description: word in the position `i` in the sentence
        if j == lword:
            print('"'+lword+'" is in position ' + str(i+1) + '.')
            break # not necessary to continue the iteration
else: # if lword not in splitlowersen:
    print ('"' + lword + '" is not in sentence!')
print("End")
```

One of the things you should notice with particular attention is the change in type of `splitlowersen`. There's no validation when assigning values to variables in python, unless you make your own (such as [`setter` methods of properties](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36943813/3026320))

Another thing, I'm using python 2.7, hence the use of [`raw_input` instead of `input`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800846/differences-between-input-and-raw-input). In 3.0 you must use `input`.