# Trying to convert a binary string into decimal, it is not calculating correctly and I do not understand why

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm attempting to get a binary string from a user and convert it into decimal. However when I do this I am not getting the right total, I'm getting numbers bigger than what their decimal conversion is and I cannot understand why for some reason... Thank you.

I have tried to change around the variables

```
binary_str = input("Please input the binary string: ")

Power = 7
Total = 0

for char in binary_str:
    product = int(char) * 2**Power
    Total += product
    set_power = Power - 1


print(Total)
```

The output was 512 when the number was supposed to be in the 200s

Comment: Use [raw_input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800846/differences-between-input-and-raw-input) instead, otherwise you'll get a evaluated object based on your input. If you're actually using python3.

Comment: Shouldn't you use `Power = Power - 1`? You are not using `set_power` anywhere

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to do this, `int` will do this for you, try this:

```
binary_str = input("Please input the binary string: ")
t = int(binary_str, 2)
```

`t` will be your expected result.

Answer (score 0):

The following will work for your purpose:

```
binary_str = input("Please input the binary string: ")
power = len(binary_str)-1
total = 0

for char in binary_str:
    total += int(char) * 2**power
    power -=1
print(total)
```

In our solution `set_power` has nothing to do with `Power` and the value of `Power` does not change in each iteration. So, the value multiplied in each digit would be `2**7` for all digits. If you want to fix it consider `Power-=1` like the shown code.